# Rails upload csv or text file with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am building a rails application that associates serial #'s with software titles. For instance, I have a software title, and need to be able to upload batches of serial #'s(codes) and associate it with that specific software title. It needs to be simple enough for a user(authenticated) to click an upload link, select a software title from a dropdown and hit import. Here is what I have so far... It does not necessarily have to be a csv it could be a text file too. I just need help figuring out the best way to accomplish this.

[Code Upload UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVIE5.png)

**Code Schema**

```
create_table "codes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "software_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "label"
    t.string   "code"
    t.string   "in_use"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "codes", ["software_id"], name: "index_codes_on_software_id"
  add_index "codes", ["user_id"], name: "index_codes_on_user_id"
```

**Code 'form' for UI**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@code) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :software %>
    <%= f.input :label %>
    <%= f.input :code %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.file_field :code %>
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Upload Codes", class: 'btn btn-warning' %>
  </div>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

**Code.rb Model**

```
class Code < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :software
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :software

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Code.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

**Software.rb Model**

```
class Software < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :software_assigns
  has_many :products, through: :software_assigns
  has_many :software_downloads
  has_many :codes
end
```

**Codes Controller**

```
class CodesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :verify_admin
  before_action :set_code, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /codes
  # GET /codes.json
  def index
    @codes = Code.all
  end

  # GET /codes/1
  # GET /codes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /codes/new
  def new
    @code = Code.new
  end

  # GET /codes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /codes
  # POST /codes.json
  def create
    @code = Code.new(code_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @code.save
        format.html { redirect_to @code, notice: 'Codes were successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /codes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /codes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @code.update(code_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @code, notice: 'Codes were successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /codes/1
  # DELETE /codes/1.json
  def destroy
    @code.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to codes_url, notice: 'Codes were successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end

  def import
    Code.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to codes_path, notice: 'Codes were successfully uploaded!'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_code
      @code = Code.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def code_params
      params.require(:code).permit(:software_id, :label, :code)
    end
end
```

Comment: could you show your schema for your `codes` table?

Comment: I added the schema to my original post. Thanks Michael ;)

Comment: Checkout my comment on pitabas prathal's answer below and let me know if that helps.

Comment: How is the software referred to in the csv file? Does it have a column for softward_id? Or does it refer to it by some other property, like its name?

Comment: The csv just has a single column with a header called 'code' without quotes. Each row is a unique serial num. Also I have posted this topic on this forum at [GoRails](https://gorails.com/forum/import-a-csv-with-associations) and Chris' suggestion references the correct software upon import, however for the code column it only bring in the object in memory and looks like this `#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fca7d9c8098>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - doing a lot of communication in the comments and I think I can put together an answer now.

So, as per my edit to pitabas prathal's answer, you need to look for by the `:code` key in the code_params hash, but since the Code class has no idea that you've got a `code_params[:software_id]` to refer to, you'll need to pass that along. So your import method becomes:

**code.rb**

```
def self.import(file, software_id)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    code = Code.new row.to_hash
    code.software_id = software_id
    code.save!
  end
end
```

Then, your call to this method with the new argument, from the `create` action (or your `import` method on the controller):

```
Code.import(code_params[:code], code_params[:software_id])
```

Now, you are giving your Code class all the information it needs to associate the new `Code` objects with the appropriate `Software` object.

**Edit**

In your GoRails post, Chris Oliver's answer would also work, with one edit:

```
@software = Software.find(params[:software_id])
```

will not work - `params[:software_id]` is nil. You can access `software_id` from the `code_params` hash:

```
@software = Software.find(code_params[:software_id])
```

or by adding the [:code] key in to the params reference like so:

```
@software = Software.find(params[:code][:software_id])
```

since [:software_id] is inside the [:code] array in the `params` hash.

Comment: ...and now that I look at it, it's basically what Chris Oliver said on your GoRails post. The main difference, again, is using `code_params[:software_id]` rather than `params[:software_id]`.